# Custom compare for GroupBy method in a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to put objects with specific values(in this case `(int?)null`) in different groups.

So this:

```
Id  NullableInt
A      1
B      2
C      1
D     null
E     null
F      1
G     null
```

Should end up as this:

```
Key   Ids
1      A, C, F
2      B
null   D
null   E
null   G
```

I am using `.GroupBy` with a custom comparer to try and achieve this.

The problem is that getting an error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

When I test the LINQ expression on its own it works so I assume that its not supported or works differently in Entity Framework, but I can't find any information on it.

My code (simplified):

```
var result = db.Table
    ...
    .GroupBy(
        t => t.NullableInt,
        new NullNotEqualComprare())
    ...
    .ToList();
```

Obviously I want to do as much as possible in the database itself.

The Comparer code:

```
    private class NullNotEqualComparer : IEqualityComparer<int?>
    {
        public bool Equals(int? x, int? y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return x.Value == y.Value;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int? obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong and if it is not supported, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with a bit of a hack, but its quite simple and works well. I thought I would write it down here since it might be useful for others.

In my question the `NullableInt` is actually an id to a different table and so I know that it will always be above zero.

For this reason I can do something like this:

```
var result = db.Table
    ...
    .GroupBy(t => t.NullableInt ?? int.MinValue + t.Id)
    ...
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. According to MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities , linq-to-entities GroupBy does not support comparer.
2. According to your requirement, you can try 2 functions. First block filters all null keys, then second blocks group by not-null keys. Like this

   ```
    var nullKeyList = db.Table.Where(x => x.NullableInt == null).ToList();

    var valueKeyGroup = db.Table.Where(x => x.NullableInt != null)
                       .GroupBy(t => t.NullableInt).ToList();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Alas, you forgot to write exactly the requirements of your groups. I can't deduct it from your comparer, because the comparer is not correct.

According to your comparer, if x equals null, then x does not equal x

```
IEqualityComparer<int?> comparer = new NullNotEqualComparer();
int? x = null;
bool b = comparer(x, x);
```

Therefore x wouldn't be in the same group as x.

Let's talk later about the comparer, first let's explain the exception.

### IQueryable can't use IEqualityComparer

An `IQueryable<...>` has an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Expression represents in a generic form the query that must be executed; the Provider knows which process will execute the query (usually a database management system) and which language is used to communicate with that process (usually SQL).

As long as you concatenate LINQ statements that return `IQueryable<...>`, only the `Expression` is changed. The database is not contacted, the query is not executed. Only when you start enumerating by calling `GetEnumerator()` (either directly, or deep-down in another function, like `ToList()`, or `foreach`), the Expression is sent to the Provider who will try to translate the Expression into SQL, and execute the query. The returned data is presented as an `IEnumerator<...>`, which you can use to access the returned items one by one.

The problem is, that the Provider does not know your `NullNotEqualComparer`, and thus can't translate it into SQL. In fact, there are a several LINQ methods that are not supported by LINQ-to-Entities. See [Supported and Unsupported Methods (LINQ to Entities)]
[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

So you'll have to try to put the comparison in the keySelector of the GroupBy.

### Intermezzo: your NullNotEqualComparer

Your equality comparer is not a good comparer. It does not meet the requirement that x equals x:

```
IEqualityComparer<int?> comparer = new NullNotEqualComparer();
int? x = null;
bool b = comparer.Equals(x, x);

int? y = x;
bool c = comparer.Equals(x, y);

int? z = null;
bool d = comparer.Equals(x, z);
```

What do you expect, and what are the results?

Almost always, a proper Equality comparer starts with the same four lines:

```
public bool equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
{
    if (x == null) return y == null; // true if both null, false if x null, y not null
    if (y == null) return false;     // false, because x != null and y == null

    // the following two lines are just for efficiency:
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) return true;
    if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;

    // here starts the real comparison:
    ...
}
```

In rare occasions you want different types to be equal objects. In that case you won't check on type.

**GetHashCode** is used to check in a fast way that two object are different. If you have to compare equality of a thousand objects, and you can easily find out that 990 of them are different, than you only have to fully check the last 10 elements.

Think of a class with 20 properties. For full equality you need to check all 20 properties. If you choose your GetHashCode wise, it may not be necessary to check all 20 properties.

For instance, if you want to find all persons living on the same address, you'll have to check Country, City, PostCode, Street, HouseNumber, ...

A quick way to eliminate most people from your input sequence, would be to check on PostCode only: if two people have different PostCode, they won't be living on the same address.

Therefore, the only requirement on your GetHashCode would be: if `Equals(x, y)`, then `GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y)`. Mind you: not the other way round: there may be different x and y, that have the same HashCode. This is easy to see: GetHashCode returns an Int32, so there must be several Int64 objects that share their HashCode.

```
EqualityComparer<int?> comparer = new NullNotEqualComparer();
int? x = null;
int y = comparer.GetHashcode(x);   // <== Exception!
```

### Back to your question

It seems to me that you created this equality comparer, because you want a separate group for all items in your table that have a value for t.NullableInt equal to null.

```
Id  NullableInt
A      1
B      2
C      1
D     null
E     null
F      1
G     null
```

You want three groups:

- Key 1, elements with Id A, C, F
- Key 2, element with Id B
- Key null, elements with Id D, E, G

If this is what you want, you can use the [default comparer for class `Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.equals?view=netcore-3.1):

- HasValue of both x and y are false: return true
- HasValue of both x and y are true: return x.Value == y.Value
- in all other cases: return false.

Assuming you have a method to translate the rows of your dt.Table to an IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<MyClass> tableRows = db.Table.ToMyClass();
var result = tableRows.GroupBy(row => row.NullableInt);
```

Comment: Thanks for an in depth answer. I guess I might have worded my question incorrectly but in the first line I write `I want to put objects with specific values(in this case (int?)null) in different groups.` by this I mean that I want entities with value `null` to end up in different groups.